# Set an image and a title in a button from package android

Tags: android, button, package

How can i set an image to the left and the text center of this type of button.

e.g

icon + text

here is my button.

```
<packagename.LoginButton
android:id="@+id/btnconnect"
android:layout_width="180dp"
android:layout_height="35dp"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView1"
android:drawableLeft="@drawable/f_logo"
android:text="@string/connect" />
```

Comment: use `android:gravity="center_horizontal"`

Comment: yes but when i run the project the button is invisible no resources are added to it

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/browsefilebtn"
    style="@style/ButtonText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:textSize="12sp" 
    android:textColor="#FF4848"
    android:width="240dp"
    android:text="@string/selectmultiple"
    android:background="@drawable/btn_black"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/clip_attachement" />
```

Comment: `android:textSize` should be in `sp` and not in `dp`

Comment: @sophia : please add a capture image of your button and your layout xml

Answer (score 0):

you can try this.. In case you need space between image and label you can give padding

```
android:id="@+id/button"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
android:drawableLeft="@drawable/image"
android:text="button"
android:textColor="0F0F0F"
android:textSize="25sp"
android:textStyle="bold" />
```